# How to exit Application from JMenu item?

Tags: java, swing, exit, joptionpane, jmenuitem

From the Jframe I have a menu, inside it I have a menu item called Exit. I want the program so when exit is clicked the application exits. but before a JOptionPane appears to ask if you would like to exit. I tried this but it won't work.

```
private void jExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
      {                                      

            String toExit = String.valueOf(jExit);


        if(jExit.equals(evt.getActionCommand())){

         int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
         JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Would You Like to Exit?","Warning",dialogButton);

         if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            System.exit(0);
         }

    }      
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). 
Please add the **complete error message** and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve).

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: @TimothyTruckle There is no error messages. When running the application and clicking on the Exit from the menu item nothing happens.

Comment: Please post an MCVE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson That is the only code that i have

Comment: where exactly do you assign the user selection to your variable `dialogButton`?

Comment: *"That is the only code that i have"* That is not a complete class definition, does not include the imports or a `main(String[])`. Without those, it would not run. It would not even compile.

Comment: The only imports i have for it are these:                                                              
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

Comment: I didnt assign it anywhere but it should have given me an error for that.. the only dialog button i mentioned was in that snippet i put here.

Comment: And yes from my code there is mentioned the  main(String[]) becuase i used them for other thing (combo boxes etc) Which these do not even need to be used for this.

Comment: `ActionListener` has a method called `actionPerformed`, but you seem to have called your method `jExitActionPerformed`. I don't think your code will be called because of this name mismatch.

Comment: There are other problems with this code, too, but the method-name-mismatch is the most glaring at the moment.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz That method was created on its own. That is when from the design of the GUI. I just double clicked on the menu item from the design and this got created like that.

Comment: What happens is you replace all the code in your snippet with `System.exit(0)`? If it doesn't quit your program than your GUI builder has failed you.

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes I've shown below. Basically I've taken `showConfirmDialod` method's return value to `response` variable. And use that in the `if` condition.

```
private void jExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
  String toExit = String.valueOf(jExit);

  if (jExit.equals(evt.getActionCommand()))
  {
    int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
    int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would You Like to Exit?", "Warning", dialogButton);

    if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work either. I spend a bit time arranging and tried different methods and one of them worked. I will post the answer . Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
 private void jExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,"Do you want to Exit? ", 
     "Confirm",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

     if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
     {
        System.exit(0);
     } 
}
```